# Lambda Expression to create a map with Integer as key and List as value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Question : Solve the following via lambda Expressions. Given a list of Strings, create a map where

```
Key=Integer(string.length)
value=List
```

If two strings matches with the length, create a list of all such matching length of strings.

I have no clue as how to create a list for all matching strings lengths within the stream!! I tried the following way, which gives me exception of duplicate Key, which is obvious.

```
private static void changeToMap(List<String> listString)
{
    Map<Integer, String> map=listString.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x->x.toString().length(),x->x));
    System.out.println(map);        
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is precisely what the [`groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) collector was designed to do:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = 
    listString.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length));
```

Note, BTW, that your code defined map as `Map<Integer, String>`, whereas according to the description of the problem, it should be defined as `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, as the snippet above defines it.

Comment: Hey Thank you!! This is what i was seraching!! :) Yes my declaration of map according to requirement is not allighned because i could implement the list, so declared that way!!